# Android screen freezes, while saving to DB

Tags: android

Following is my coding for downloading the data from web and on post execute I save it to DB and then update the ListAdapter for GUI.

Problem is when saving to the DB, screen freezes for the time it is getting saved in DB and for 600 records it is about 20 secs.

Please let me know, how can I change this, so that UI do not freeze.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public DownloadWebPageTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();



            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),

            "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);


            }

        }



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String response = "";

        for (String url : urls) {

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            try {

                InputStream content = client.execute(httpGet).getEntity()

                .getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(

                new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                    response += s;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return response;

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        try {



            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL COURSES")) {
                dbList = db.getAllCourseDBs(type);

                if (dbList.isEmpty())

                {
                progressDialog.dismiss();


                }






            if((result==null)|| result.isEmpty())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL COURSES")) {
                    db.deleteAllCourseByTypeDB(type);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.deleteAllCourseByCategoryIdDB(category_id);

                }



            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data_one = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                db.deleteAllCourseCategoryByTypeDB(type);


                for (int j = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)

                {

                    CourseDB nbnt = new CourseDB();


                    long insideStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String crsCd=null, crsTitle=null;
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Area of Training")) {




                            crsCd = json_data.getString("courseCd");

                         crsTitle = json_data.getString("courseTitle");



                    }
                    else{


                    crsCd = (json_data.getString("crsCd"));


                     crsTitle = (json_data.getString("crsTitle"));
                    }



                    nbnt.setcourse_crs(crsCd);

                    nbnt.setcategory_course_type(type);

                    nbnt.setcourse_name(crsTitle);
                    nbnt.setcat_foreign_id(category_id);


                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                    System.out.println("date to be inseted in DB"+currentDateandTime);
                    nbnt.setcourse_time(currentDateandTime);
                    arrayofWebData.add(nbnt);
                    db.beginTransaction();

                    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();


                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    db.addcourseByType(nbnt, sqlDB);
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

                    db.endTransaction();

                    db.close();

                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();



                    readWebpagerating();
                     Collections.sort(arrayofWebData, new CourseDBComparator ());
                    listAdapter = new SelectArralAdapter(getActivity(),
                                arrayofWebData);

                        lv123.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                        lv123.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


                lv123.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

                    int position, long id) {

                        CourseDB planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);


                        String key = planet.getcourse_crs();

                        String KEY_ID_NOTEBOOK = db.CourseDB(key);

                        System.out.println("value if key_id" + KEY_ID_NOTEBOOK);


                        Intent intent25 = new Intent(getActivity(),


                        CourseDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent25.putExtra("course_id", key);

                        intent25.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                        intent25.putExtra("type", type);

                        intent25.putExtra("category_name", category_name);

                        startActivity(intent25);
                        getActivity().finish();

                    }

                });



            }
            }
        }
        }




    catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("log tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

Changed Code as Suggested, screen do not freeze now, but I f I move to another screen , it crashes on the post execute.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public DownloadWebPageTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL COURSES")) {
        dbList = db.getAllCourseDBs(type);
        if (dbList.isEmpty())

        {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),

            "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        }
        }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("SEARCH")){
            // DO NOTHING
        }
        else
        {
            dbList = db.getAllCourseDBByTypes(category_id, type);
            if (dbList.isEmpty())

            {

                System.out.println("the value of the dbList inside all coursestypes"+dbList.size());
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),

                "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

            }

        }



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String response = "";

        for (String url : urls) {

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            try {

                InputStream content = client.execute(httpGet).getEntity()

                .getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(

                new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                    response += s;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            System.out.println("value of the response"+response);









            //adding new */


            if((response==null)|| response.isEmpty())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL COURSES")) {
                    db.deleteAllCourseByTypeDB(type);
                }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("SEARCH")){
                    // DO NOTHING
                }
                else
                {
                    db.deleteAllCourseByCategoryIdDB(category_id);

                }



            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data_one = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                System.out.println("All the not empty");

                db.deleteAllCourseCategoryByTypeDB(type);





                for (int j = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)

                {

                    CourseDB nbnt = new CourseDB();


                    long insideStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String crsCd=null, crsTitle=null;
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Area of Training")) {
                        System.out.println("im area of tarinin");



                            crsCd = json_data.getString("courseCd");

                         crsTitle = json_data.getString("courseTitle");



                    }
                    else{


                    crsCd = (json_data.getString("crsCd"));


                     crsTitle = (json_data.getString("crsTitle"));
                    }

                    System.out.println("Time for one JSON parsing "

                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - insideStart));

                    nbnt.setcourse_crs(crsCd);

                    nbnt.setcategory_course_type(type);

                    nbnt.setcourse_name(crsTitle);
                    nbnt.setcat_foreign_id(category_id);


                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                    System.out.println("date to be inseted in DB"+currentDateandTime);
                    nbnt.setcourse_time(currentDateandTime);
                    arrayofWebData.add(nbnt);
                    db.beginTransaction();

                    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();


                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    db.addcourseByType(nbnt, sqlDB);
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

                    db.endTransaction();

                    db.close();



            }
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        }

        return response;

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL COURSES")) {
            dbList = db.getAllCourseDBs(type);

            if (dbList.isEmpty())

            {
            progressDialog.dismiss();


            }
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("SEARCH")){
                // DO NOTHING
            }
            else
            {
                dbList = db.getAllCourseDBByTypes(category_id, type);

                if (dbList.isEmpty())

                {

                    System.out.println("the value of the dbList inside all coursestypes"+dbList.size());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }

            }



                readWebpagerating();
                 Collections.sort(arrayofWebData, new CourseDBComparator ());
                listAdapter = new SelectArralAdapter(getActivity(),
                            arrayofWebData);

                    lv123.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    lv123.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


            lv123.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

                int position, long id) {

                    CourseDB planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);


                    String key = planet.getcourse_crs();

                    String KEY_ID_NOTEBOOK = db.CourseDB(key);

                    System.out.println("value if key_id" + KEY_ID_NOTEBOOK);

                    System.out.println("category id on lcick listnere inside the post ecexute" + category_id);

                    Intent intent25 = new Intent(getActivity(),


                    CourseDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent25.putExtra("course_id", key);

                    intent25.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                    intent25.putExtra("type", type);

                    intent25.putExtra("category_name", category_name);

                    startActivity(intent25);
                    getActivity().finish();

                }

            });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The database operation should be done in `doInBackground()`

Comment: you mean to say whole of the thing I am doing in postexecute or just adding everything to DB in doInBackground() and notifying listAdapter in postExecute?

Comment: Yes, add everything pertaining to db to doInBackground and then notify listadapter in onPostExecute.

Comment: Now, it do not hang, but If I change the activity from the current to another(before it finishes saving to DB), it crashes.

Comment: @Asmi, then in onPause of your Activity, call myAsyncTask.cancel(true)

Comment: I tried both onPause() and OnDestroy() but it gives Null Pointer Exception on the Async Task.

Comment: @Override
 public void onPause()
 {  
     super.onPause();     
 }
 
 public void onDestroy(){
  taskCourses.cancel(true);
  super.onDestroy();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Just like LuxuryMode says, all blocking operations need to be in background.

The problem with your approach is that you put all this in Activity, lifecycle of which is not appropriate for background operations.

Create application model that lives outside (usually in Application subclass) and move your AsyncTask there. In Activities bind to that model using simple pattern like observer/callback to update your Adapter.